# Scroll child divs under/behind parent div inner mask

Tags: css, angular, scroll, angular-flex-layout

I have a child div with a fixed height that is scrollable because the content extends the height.

The parent div has a red inside mask.

I need to scroll the elements of the child div under/behind this red inner mask. How can this be achieved ?

Here's the link to a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/sf1nQ5b5Ho4uqase) that showcases how the `messages` elements scroll over the red mask.

html

```
<div id="console" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
  <div
    id="console_toolbar"
    fxLayoutAlign="start start"
    fxLayout="row"
    fxFill
  >
    <div class="label_text">Display:</div>
    <div class="con_msg_cb">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="console_output" fxLayout="row" fxFill>
    <div id="console_msg_wrapper" fxLayout="column" fxFill>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
      <div class="cm">message</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#console {
  background-color: green;
}

div#console_toolbar {
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 100%;

  background-color: blue;
}
div#console_output{
  height: 200px;
}
div#console_msg_wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(to bottom,
        rgba(240, 255, 40, 1) 0%,
        rgba(240, 255, 40, 1) 100%),
      linear-gradient(to bottom,
        rgba(240, 40, 40, 1) 0%,
        rgba(240, 40, 40, 1) 100%);
    background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
    z-index: 100;
}
div.cm{

}
```

Comment: why not a red border?

Comment: @TemaniAfif: even with a border the text scrolls over the border. Do you have an example where it does not ?

Comment: can anybody help ?